# Como ejecutar un PHP con Ionic 2

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, http, ionic2

Al hacer la peticion de **mi-php.php** por medio de `GET` de `Http` me retorta literalmente el codigo del archivo **php** en una cadena de texto, lo que necesito es que se ejecute el archivo **php** y me retorne el resultado de la consulta a la base de datos en formato **Json**

Los codigos son:

***src/providers/servi-productos.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the ServiProductos provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ServiProductos {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ServiProductos Provider');
  }


  getPHP(){
    this.http.get("assets/php/mi-php.php").subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

***src/app/app.module.ts***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { Perfil } from '../pages/perfil/perfil';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ServiProductos } from '../providers/servi-productos';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Perfil,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      //backButtonText: 'Volver',
      iconMode: 'ios',
      modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
      modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
      tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
      pageTransition: 'ios-transition'
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Perfil,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ServiProductos,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

***src/page/perfil/perfil.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ServiProductos } from '../../providers/servi-productos';

/**
 * Generated class for the Perfil page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-perfil',
  templateUrl: 'perfil.html',
})
export class Perfil {
    login: {username?: string, password?: string} = {};
  submitted = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public serviProduct: ServiProductos) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Perfil');
    this.serviProduct.getPHP();
  }

}
```

***src/assets/php/mi-php.php***

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
console.log("php corriendo");
system.out.println("some")
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","nombreBD");


$query="SELECT * FROM nombreTabla;


$result = $conn->query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$conn->close();

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo un error en tu codigo de la pregunta y es que FALTA UNA DOBLE COMILLA EN TU SELECT :

```
$query="SELECT * FROM nombreTabla";


$result = $conn->query($query);
$conn->close();

echo $result;
```

Y segundo, si quieres obtener datos lo normal seria devolver un `json`. (Complementando con la respuesta de Jorge)

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: no funciona, sigo teniendo el mismo problema, lo que retorna del metodo GET es esto: 

"<?php↵↵header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");↵header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");↵console.log("php corriendo");↵system.out.println("some")↵$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","allmarket");↵$campos="";↵$tabla="";
↵$query="";↵$query="SELECT * FROM nombreTabla";↵↵$result = $conn->query($query);↵↵$rows = array();↵while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {↵    $rows[] = $r;↵}↵↵$conn->close();↵↵echo json_encode($rows);↵↵?> "  eso viene siendo literalmente el codigo del archivo php

Comment: es raro, es como si no interpretara tu codigo php.. pregunta... 1) Tienes las etiquetas `<?php ?>` y 2) Estas seguro que corre php donde tienes hospedado el archivo?

Comment: si tiene las etiqueras y el archivo esta en la ruta src/assets/php/mi-php.php de un servido local que corro por consola con el comando de ionic serve

Comment: espera, eso si que no lo entendi. Corres un servidor local con `ionic serve` y esperas que te devuelva desde ahi el codigo php? Eso no funcionara, por eso te lo muestra como texto, ahi NO se compila codigo PHP. Lo que puedes hacer es instalar XAMPP en tu windows y montar ahi el codigo PHP y consumirlo, tambien si es que tienes algun servidor en la nube, pero de otra forma jamas va a funcionar

Comment: voy a proba con XAMMP

Comment: perfecto, cualquier duda me comentas, aunque la respuesta que te deje no deberia tener ningun problema. Si te ayudo recuerda marcarla. Un saludo y quedo atento!

Comment: de alguna manera se puede hacer una consulta a una base de datos mysql sin usar php?, en un proyecto anterior use la tecnología de node.js y con el modulo de mysql lograba la conexión y consultas a la base de datos, el asunto es que usando la tecnología de ionic no se como integrarla con la de node.js, hasta donde tengo entendido cuando uno crea un proyecto con ionic el instalar la carpeta de node_modules y ahí puedo encontrar el modulo de mysql que necesito, pero como dije, no se como hacer el llamado a este modulo desde los archivos de mi proyecto con ionic.

Comment: @DanielEnriqueRodriguezCaste la verdad es que desconozco eso. Generalmente las conexiones a bases de datos que hago en mis aplicaciones con Ionic son a traves de servicios webs que si estan conectados a la base de datos (sea mysql, sql server, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Te falta esto

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: no funciona, sigo teniendo el mismo problema, lo que retorna del metodo GET es esto: "<?php↵↵header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");↵header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");↵console.log("php corriendo");↵system.out.println("some")↵$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","allmarket");↵$campos="";↵$tabla=""; ↵$query="";↵$query="SELECT * FROM nombreTabla";↵↵$result = $conn->query($query);↵↵$rows = array();↵while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {↵ $rows[] = $r;↵}↵↵$conn->close();↵↵echo json_encode($rows);↵↵?> " eso viene siendo literalmente el codigo del archivo php

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con el codigo actual, adiciona el script de la tabla y te ayudo a validar